# How to use psycopg2 to insert data into a postgres Database

Tags: python-3.x, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I have created an app using flask, it takes an input from a user and saves the input into the Postgres Database here's the code:

```
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
    import psycopg2 as pg2
    import exquixdb

    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/questions', methods=["POST"])
    def post_question():
        request_data = request.json

        table = ("INSERT INTO question(id, question) VALUES(%s,%s)", (1003, str(request_data['question'])))
        exquixdb.db.create(table)
        app.logger.info("adding questions")



        return "question saved"


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True, port=8989)
```

I've created a database Module the code is:

```
# Module exquizdb.py
import psycopg2 as pg2


class Database():
    def db_connect(self, db="exquizdb", user="jim", pas="password", port=5433):
        global conn
        self.conn = pg2.connect(database=db, user=user, password=pas, port=port)
        global cur
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def close(self):
        self.cur.close()
        self.conn.close()

    def query(self, query):
        self.cur.execute(query)
        self.close()

    def create(self, table):
        self.cur.execute(table)
        self.conn.commit()
        self.close()


db = Database()

table = ("INSERT INTO question(id, question) VALUES(%s,%s)", (1003, 'Test'))

db.create(table)
```

so when I run the code I get (AttributeError: 'Database' object has no attribute 'cur') I am new database and python. So i don't know how to fix it. How do I fix the problem. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is as a result of not making proper use of `Class`. The `global` is not needed as the variables could have been initiated in the class constructor.

Also, the create and query method can be defined as one. Closing the connection after every query means you will have to create a new connection before running a new query.

NOTE: I refactored the `query` and `create` method as `execute_query`. Also the methods can still be improved on for proper error handling. Adding a `try and catch` block can suffice.

```
# Module exquizdb.py
import psycopg2 as pg2


class Database:
  def __init__(self, db, username, password, port):
    self.db = db
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.port = port
    self.cur = None
    self.conn = None

  def connect(self):
    self.conn = pg2.connect(database=self.db, user=self.user, password=self.password, port=self.port)
    self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

  def execute_query(self, query):
    self.cur.execute(query)
    self.conn.commit()

  def close(self):
    self.cur.close()
    self.conn.close()

db = Database(db="exquizdb", user="jim", pas="password", port=5433)

db.connect()
```

```
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
    import psycopg2 as pg2
    from exquixdb import db

    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/questions', methods=["POST"])
    def post_question():
        request_data = request.json

        table = ("INSERT INTO question(id, question) VALUES(%s,%s)", (1003, str(request_data['question'])))
        db.execute_query(table)
        app.logger.info("adding questions")


        return "question saved"


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True, port=8989)
```

Comment: Neat. Thanks for sharing the refactored example with your explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation. your explanation really helped me complete the project. Thank  you very much.